# How can I convert the code in the following select tags into a radio button?

Tags: c#, html

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group row col-12">
<label for="example-text-input" class="col-3 col-form-label">Approval Status</label>
<div class="col-9">
    <select class="form-control m-input m-input--square" name="approvalstatus" required>
        @if ((int)Model.PARAMETER.APPROVALSTATUS == 4)
        {
            <option selected value="4">Shipable</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="4">Shipable</option>
        }
        @if ((int)Model.PARAMETER.APPROVALSTATUS == 1)
        {
            <option selected value="1">Suggestion</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="1">Suggestion</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

> There are two options in the above code, I want to show these two options with radio button, not with select. In my own experiments, the changes I made always overlapped and I could not make it dynamic. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are expecting,

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group row col-12">
<label for="example-text-input" class="col-3 col-form-label">Approval Status</label>
<div class="col-9">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="approvalstatus" value="4" 
            @if ((int)Model.PARAMETER.APPROVALSTATUS == 4)
            {
                checked
            }
        > Shipable
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="approvalstatus" value="1" 
            @if ((int)Model.PARAMETER.APPROVALSTATUS == 1)
            {
                checked
            }
        > Suggestion
    </label>
</div>
```

updated: as Hans suggest you do it as,

```
<input type="radio" name="approvalstatus" value="4" checked=@((int)Model.PARAMETER.APPROVALSTATUS == 4) required> Shipable
```

Comment: `checked=@((int)Model.PARAMETER.APPROVALSTATUS == 4)` would also work - Razor knows about boolean attributes

Comment: Where exactly do I write the "checked" in the code?

Comment: @ismailtemel should be added to the radio button element